# Subtracting Totals in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report with a grouping of Category which each present their own totals lines.  I would like to subtract the total of one group from the total of a separate group.

```
Group       Clients        Revenue     ATC
Called      1000            50000      50.00
Control     100             1000       10.00
```

Here is what I want to do:

```
Variance    900             49000      40.00
```

Keep in mind that the called and control are already set as a grouping and there is underlying data that can be expanded to show each store's data.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the variance I assume you only have two groups.

Try this for Clients:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Group.Value="Called",Fields!Clients.Value,0))
-
Sum(IIF(Fields!Group.Value="Control",Fields!Clients.Value,0))
```

This for Revenue:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Group.Value="Called",Fields!Revenue.Value,0))
-
Sum(IIF(Fields!Group.Value="Control",Fields!Revenue.Value,0))
```

And this for ATC:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Group.Value="Called",Fields!ATC.Value,0))
-
Sum(IIF(Fields!Group.Value="Control",Fields!ATC.Value,0))
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.  I was trying to make it to complex by using the built in grouping when didn't need to.